# The local variable assignment was printed as output on asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view

I have a script like below on my View:

```
@{int count = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div >
        <div class="col-md-4"><img src="@item.ImageLink" />           
        @(count = count +1 );           
        @if(count ==3)
        {
            @(count = 0);
            @Html.Raw("<div class=\"clearfix visible-md\"></div>");
        }
       </div>
    </div>
}
```

The problem here is : in addition to the imageLink, the output also contain the value of count when it is assigned with value (meaning that it will print some number: 1,2,3,0 - which is value of count in each loop)

How can I resolve it?

Thanks & regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use parentheses it's output will be submitted as part of the HTML. You can use curly braces for code block as below.

```
@{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="@item.ImageLink" />
            @{count = count + 1;}
            @if (count == 3)
            {
                count = 0;
                @Html.Raw("<div class=\"clearfix visible-md\"></div>");
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    }
}
```